# Postgresql - psql cancelling statement

Tags: postgresql, psql

when I issue a "delete" statement in psql prompt and then cancel it while running (by pressing Ctrl-C), which is confirmed by "ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request", can I be sure that no rows were deleted or should I assume some rows might have been deleted?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Regards,
Jacek

Answer (score 1):

A DELETE [... WHERE ...] statement executes as a single transaction, so there are only two possible outcomes:

1. The database is unchanged (no rows are deleted).
2. All the rows were deleted.

If the transaction is aborted by cancelling, you have outcome #1 - no change.

#2 would only arise if your cancellation was too late to abort the transaction.

Comment: To avoid case #2, `auto-commit` can be turned off (`\set AUTOCOMMIT off`, can be added to `.psqlrc` to be a default), and an explicit `commit` would be required to make the delete permanent.